# Packaging WinForms application along with native DLL

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

Trying to figure out how to package the following solution with Visual Studio 2017 Desktop Bridge (Application Packaging Project):

1. .NET Library DLL.
2. WinForms executable referencing 1.
3. Native C++ DLL exporting some functions used by 1 and 2 with [DllImport].

I added project 2 to Applications section of a package and buit it. In the target folder I have EXE (from project 2) and DLL (from project 1).

And the question is: how to correctly add the project 3 (native c++ library) to a package? I have x86 and x64 project configurations for this DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it - see screenshots below for illustration:

1) create a folder in your Winforms project as the target for your native DLL(s)

2) add a post-build event step to copy the native DLL to that folder

3) in that folder, mark the DLL as part of the project

4) Make sure properties are set to "Content" and "Copy to output"

5) now the packaging project will pick up the native DLL and include it in the package

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: And what about x86/x64 configurations? It looks like I'll need to edit *.csproj file for the WinFormsApp manually to add conditions to include either x64 or x86 NativeDll version depending on WinFormsApp bitness, right?

Comment: You can use the configuration manager UI for the solution to configure your x86 and x64 packages accordingly, so the right flavor of your native DLL gets packaged into the right package. I have added more screenshots to clarify this part.

Comment: I don't understand why someone would downvote this without an explanation. After some hesitation due to that, this ended up being the only solution I could find that worked for me for a native (non-COM) DLL.

Comment: @thims, I'm not sure if Stefan's last comment would solve your issue regarding x86/x64 reliably, as it seems to rely on overwriting a single DLL. I had a similar need for Debug vs. Release, which I solved by having a separate DLL for each configuration and adding a Condition for each included DLL in the project file. You can do the same for x86 vs x64 by adding conditions for $(Platform). Visual Studio doesn't expose the Condition tag in the UI unfortunately, so it needs to be added manually. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-exclude-files-from-the-build

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT - Is it possible to [DllImport] our c++ dlls and call it in a FullTrust desktop app? Most of the logic of our app is in c++.

Comment: Yes. Please open a new question for this if more info is needed.