# Satellite assemblies stripped out of package when using Desktop Bridge

Tags: wpf, desktop-bridge

When I build my desktop bridge Package project, if I dig into the bin folder I can see all the `VidCoder.resources.dll` files in the language subfolders (bs, cs, de, es, eu, etc). But when I make the package for the store, almost all of these DLLs are stripped out, so the final product is missing most of the translations. When I unzip the appxbundle / appx files, the main executable is there but only "zh/VidCoder.resources.dll" remains.

How do I stop these satellite assemblies from getting stripped out when I make the package?

(edit) Also tried adding this to the .appxmanifest, but it didn't help:

```
<Resources>
  <Resource Language="EN-US" />
  <Resource Language="ES-ES" />
</Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, it has been fixed in Visual Studio 2017 Update 15.7

Comment: It's still broken for me in Visual Studio 15.7 Preview 3. Can you point me to the bug/issue?

Comment: It's fixed in Visual Studio 15.7 Preview 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the Dlls into the project's package, see this similar thread and have a try:

[Packaging WinForms application along with native DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754557/packaging-winforms-application-along-with-native-dll/48772581#48772581)

Comment: But my WPF project that creates the resource DLLs is the application project. I don't know how you'd include the output DLLs of the project as input content DLLs. It would make so much more sense to tell whatever is packing up the appx that it should include those.